# How to rename folder/file in Visual Studio 2019 in debug mode in React application

Tags: reactjs, .net, visual-studio-2019

I have used the project template with React.js and .NET 5.

I want to run my project in debug mode and be able to add/rename folders and jsx/tsx files in my React app folder. Currently the Visual Studio 2019 does not allow to do this.

I have already configured the options in `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Edit and Continue` - but it does not work.

Is it possible to somehow configure Visual Studio 2019 to allow add/rename folders and typescript/javascript files during debugging the app?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of VS2019 and I can rename the folders of a react app (click and wait or context menu+rename or F2). Can you be more specific about "VS does not alow this" ? But I'm not doing this during debugging, which make sense not to do this. Why do you need to do this during debug ?

Comment: I need it because, the .NET Core app is running in the background and I want to add/modify typescript files which are automatically compiled by webpack. I run whole app and I can add/modify files for react.